# findbugs, retrolambda and Android

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, findbugs

I'm using `Android studio 1.4.1` and I'm trying to setup findbugs but even setting the exclude xml with `R` and Manifest findbugs still analise them.

I want to:

1. Setup `findbugs` with android to avoid `R` and all of those generated things, like `ViewBinder` and `Lambda`.

Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'findbugs'
apply plugin: 'pmd'

findbugs {
  ignoreFailures = true
  reportsDir = file("$project.buildDir/outputs/")
  reportLevel = "low"
  effort = "max"
  excludeFilter = file("../setup/findbugs-exclude.xml")
}

pmd {
  ignoreFailures = true
  reportsDir = file("$project.buildDir/outputs/")
}

task findbugs(type: FindBugs, dependsOn: assembleDebug) {
  description 'Run findbugs'
  group 'verification'

  classes = fileTree("build/intermediates/classes/debug/")
  source = fileTree('src/main/java')
  classpath = files()

  reports {
    xml.enabled = false
    html.enabled = true
  }
}

task pmd(type: Pmd, dependsOn: assembleDebug) {
  description 'Run pmd'
  group 'verification'

  ruleSets = ["java-basic", "java-braces", "java-strings", "java-design", "java-unusedcode"]
  source = fileTree('src/main/java')

  reports {
    xml.enabled = false
    html.enabled = true
  }
}

check.doLast {
  project.tasks.getByName("findbugs").execute()
  project.tasks.getByName("pmd").execute()
}
```

findbugs-exclude.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FindBugsFilter>
  <Match>
    <Class name="~.*\.R\$.*" />
  </Match>
  <Match>
    <Class name="~.*\.Manifest\$.*" />
  </Match>
</FindBugsFilter>
```

Response:

```
Code analyzed:

/Users/me/Documents/test-android/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/android/support/design/R$anim.class
/Users/me/Documents/test-android/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/android/support/design/R$attr.class
/Users/me/Documents/test-android/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/android/support/design/R$bool.class
/Users/me/Documents/test-android/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/android/support/design/R$color.class
/Users/me/Documents/test-android/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/android/support/design/R$dimen.class
/Users/me/Documents/test-android/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/android/support/design/R$drawable.class
/Users/me/Documents/test-android/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/android/support/design/R$id.class
/Users/me/Documents/test-android/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/android/support/design/R$integer.class
/Users/me/Documents/test-android/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/android/support/design/R$layout.class
/Users/me/Documents/test-android/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/android/support/design/R$string.class

UPM Private method com.test.android.player.service.PlayerServicePresenter$$Lambda$1.get$Lambda(PlayerServicePresenter) is never called
UPM Private method com.test.android.sign_up.SignUpActivity$$Lambda$1.get$Lambda(SignUpActivity) is never called
UPM Private method com.test.android.sign_up.SignUpActivity$$Lambda$4.get$Lambda(SignUpActivity) is never called
UPM Private method com.test.android.sign_up.SignUpPresenter$$Lambda$1.get$Lambda(SignUpPresenter) is never called
UPM Private method com.test.android.sign_up.SignUpPresenter$$Lambda$2.get$Lambda(SignUpPresenter) is never called
UPM Private method com.test.android.tutorial.TutorialActivity$$Lambda$1.get$Lambda(TutorialActivity) is never called
UPM Private method com.test.android.tutorial.TutorialPresenter$$Lambda$1.get$Lambda(TutorialPresenter, String) is never called
UPM Private method com.test.android.tutorial.TutorialPresenter$$Lambda$2.get$Lambda(TutorialPresenter) is never called
UPM Private method com.test.android.tutorial.TutorialPresenter$$Lambda$3.get$Lambda(TutorialPresenter) is never called
UPM Private method com.test.android.utils.base.BaseView$$Lambda$1.get$Lambda(BaseView) is never called
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this would help. Just add to *findbugs-exclude.xml* this code:

```
<Match>
    <Bug code="UPM" />
    <Class name="~.*\$\$Lambda\$.*"/>
</Match>
```

Comment: Why do I need to put <Bug > tag inside? there's no way to avoid all the checkings for those classes?